Grafana loki queries lookup
New to Loki Grafana and coming from splunk back ground.Like how we have lookups in splunk what is equivalent that in Grafana loki.
My uses case is, in my logs I have 100's of codes and which doesn't make any sense in displaying codes to end user, instead I want to display and meaning full description by storing the description for each code  and doing lookup in my lookup file(normally it will be .csv file in splunk) How do I do that in Grafana loki.



Code
Meaning




23445
Automation


12345
Development



I want to store code and description and do a lookup while querying and displaying in a dashboard.
